# How to validate Offline cached data and data coming from API

Tags: android, android-room

I am trying to make an app in which I am going to use room database for offline data caching and using NodeJs and MongoDB as a backend service.
What I am going to do is when app first opens it fetches data from server and stores in room database from where it shows in database.
My problem is whenever some new data is updated on server how would I know whether it is available in room database and when to fire server request.
Someone please let me know how can achieve this any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to implement some sort of routine where you can check and validate (update) the data. However, this will depend on the importance of the data and rather if it should be updated and how often.

These are some of the solutions you can look at:

- **Long/short polling** - Client Pull
- **WebSockets** - Server Push
- **Server-Sent Events** - Server Push

I would probably use some sort of real-time communication (web sockets) or use a real-time database to notify the app of changes when something needs to get updated. That said it would also depend on the technology, for instance, Firebase already offers [offline caching](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality in multiple ways

1. Configure firebase notification in your app, whenever any server side data update happen just trigger a notification, based on that you can call api and store data in room.
2. Maintain some version code related to updated server side data in your api, based on that version code you can write logic for storing data in room.

Comment: Could you direct me to any good example of that in which above operation is implemented.

Comment: firebase push notification you can try https://android.jlelse.eu/android-push-notification-using-firebase-and-advanced-rest-client-3858daff2f50